# Wave like behaviour

Tags: waves, wave-particle-duality

Sorry if this is a repeat but I'm curious if wavelength $\lambda=h/p$ then does that imply that we would be able to observe the wavelike properties of a very still object? For example an average human weighing $65\ \mathrm{kg}$ travelling at $10^{-28}\ \mathrm{m/s}$ should have a detectable wavelength of $101.94\ \mathrm{nm}$ so would they exhibit wavelike behaviour?

Comment: Hopefully someone who knows more about this subject than me comments on this, but my understanding is that it has been difficult to demonstrate the wave-like properties of macroscopic objects such as a human being or even much smaller objects such as a pebble because of the difficulty of isolating such objects. Any interaction of a macroscopic object with anything else constitutes a "measurement" of it, and that collapses the quantum mechanical wave function associated with the object. Again, I'm not an expert on this and hopefully someone else comments on this.

Comment: no, we still cannot measure wavelength. since human has very big size, such small wavelength would lie within him in nanometers which can not de measured. our natural metabolic wavelengths of electric signals are even of more wavelength. Among so many wavelengths detecting such small wavelength of your motion is impossible.

Comment: The average human is a lot bigger than $101.94$ nanometers.  You're not going to have an easy time noticing wavelike behavior of an extended physical object that is so many orders of magnitude larger than its own theoretical wavelength.  Also, from the physics point of view, a live human is not "an object", but a collection of an astronomical number of elasticly bound atoms.  In order for a human to behave like a single physical object, she/he would have to be very, _very_ cold.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, any object will have a wave-like nature, this is very interesting and perfectly real. The thing and the reason why we don't see the macroscopic world around us acts a little like the quantum world is that nothing as a small enough momentum. $h$ you know is very very small about $10^{-33} kg \space m^2 /s$ so to be able to observe this wave-like nature of this it should have a momentum which ridiculously small. Nothing has small enough velocity to make the objects exhibit this nature, because their masses is way bigger than anything in the quantum world and trying to have as you said a velocity of about $10^{-28} m/s$ would be almost impossible because everything moves way faster and everything interacts with one another. For example right know you can be completely still and still move in space at an incrdible velocity auroud the sun and even more aroud the galaxy. But the answer to your question is yes, everything posseses its wave-like nature. So we are little thinking waves, really little (with an incredibly small wave-lenght).

For technicality the wavelength of matter is given by the De Broglie wavelength, $\lambda$ where:

$$\lambda=\frac{h}{p}$$

where $p$ is the momentum: for objects moving much slower than the speed of light in the current context, $p=mv$ where $m$ is rest mass and $v$ is the velocity of the matter.